# Distributed testing using console - Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, distributed-testing

I found this link on remotely running my tests on different machines

http://performancetestingwithjmeter.blogspot.in/2012/09/distributed-load-testing-in-jmeter.html

but this link defines process using UI,

I want to done Distributed load testing via console,

What I should done to make Distributed(Master/Slave) testing work from console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jmeter with command option `-r` from master. [Reference](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)